# cannot reduce the size of my Btrfs partition

Tags: btrfs

I need to free up 4T on my LVM which is mainly taken by a Btrfs filesystem
mounted on `/data`.
I did:

```
# btrfs fi resize -h
btrfs filesystem resize: too few arguments
usage: btrfs filesystem resize [devid:][+/-]<newsize>[kKmMgGtTpPeE]|[devid:]max <path>

    Resize a filesystem

    If 'max' is passed, the filesystem will occupy all available space
    on the device 'devid'.
    [kK] means KiB, which denotes 1KiB = 1024B, 1MiB = 1024KiB, etc.
```

so it looks I should do:

```
btrfs filesystem resize -4T /data
```

which gives an error:

```
Resize '/data' of '-4T'
ERROR: unable to resize '/data': Invalid argument
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ran into this when trying to use a fraction (29.5G, 29.4G, 29.6G) but the command ran fine with 29G.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be running a newer version of the Btrfs tools

```
$ btrfs --version
Btrfs v3.12
$ btrfs filesystem resize -h
btrfs filesystem resize: too few arguments
usage: btrfs filesystem resize [devid:][+/-]<newsize>[gkm]|[devid:]max <path>

    Resize a filesystem

    If 'max' is passed, the filesystem will occupy all available space
    on the device 'devid'.
```

although the help has been updated (I get the same "help" message as you do
in Btrfs tools v4.4), the command still only accepts `kKmMgG`.

You should use:

```
btrfs filesystem resize -4096G /data
```

to reduce the size by 4 terabytes.

Please note that contrary to some other tools that make a distinction
between k=1000 and K=1024, for `btrfs filesystem resize` both lower
and upper case this means multiples of 1024.